# How to mark seams for simple planes?

Tags: uv

I'm new to texturing in blender and I've learnt how to unwrap cylinders properly. However, what is the correct/efficient way to unwrap simple faces? The face I've selected are distorted in the UV view (become a triangle). What's the reason behind that? Any help is appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: Please add details as to what unwrapping method you have tried that resulted in distorted faces.

Comment: It's likely that you haven't placed seams on the mesh properly and used Unwrap from `U` menu. In this case mesh parts near the seam *can* be unwrapped good, others will be stretched

Comment: Try smart uv project with angle limits at 90 degrees

Comment: Try applying the scale of your model, *in object mode* (Ctrl+A)>Scale

Comment: And then unwrap your plane again

Comment: The smart uv project worked for me (temporarily). I'll update this post if there are further issues. Thank you so much for you guys' help!